# Python append: It only return the last value repeatedly

Tags: python, django, list, append

This is a part of my code.

```
dbList = []
for obj in xmlData.iter("object")
    task = TaskViewModel()
    task.id = obj.("pk")
    task.name = obj.find("field[@name='name']").text
    task.parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
    dbList.append(task)
```

My problem is it only gives me results that repeat.

my expected result is:

```
dbList = ["dale","Michelle","Fred","Debbie"]
```

but it gives me this result:

```
dbList = ["Debbie","Debbie","Debbie","Debbie"]
```

I think I should clear something.

Hi this is the example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="31">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Dale</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="32">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Michelle</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Fred</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="34">
<field name="name" type="CharField">Debbie</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
</django-objects>"
```

I have this class

```
class TaskViewModel():

     def __init__(self):
        self.id = 0
        self.name = ""
        self.parent_task_id = ""
```

so that's why i did this:

```
for obj in xmlData.iter("object")
    task = TaskViewModel()
    task.id = obj.("pk")
    task.name = obj.find("field[@name='name']").text
    task.parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
    dbList.append(task)
```

Comment: are you sure `task.id = obj.("pk")` refers to the pk attribute using the right syntax?

Comment: if `TaskViewModel` is a Django DB model, you should declare it as `class TaskViewModel(models.Model)`, assuming you have imported it as `from django.db import models`. Obviously, its attributes must change as well: use django's [model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#field-types)

Comment: The code shown obviously gives a syntax error at `obj.("pk")`. That means you haven't copied/pasted your exact code so you may well have hidden the actual problem. Please ensure you have copied the exact code you are using.

Comment: oh it should be obj.get("pk")

Answer (score 3):

Your class is wrong, you are assigning and manipulating class variables (known also as static variables in other languages) rather than instance variables. Use something like this instead:

```
class TaskViewModel():
    def __init__(self):
       self.id = 0
       self.name = ""
       self.parent_task_id = ""
```